# Cannot get the cookie in angular even using $cookies

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cookies

I have seen all the questions regarding this topic in SO.However I cannot seem to get the cookie value even after implementing.I am a newbie at this.So please forgive me for the lack of understanding.

I am sending correct login credentials via angular ajax to server which is returning a Set-Cookie property having a value.I cannot get this cookie value even after using $cookies and implementing it within $timeout.

Below is my service code:

```
userOperation.loginService = function(username,password){
return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      withCredentials: true,
      url: urlService.baseUrl+'login',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data:"username="+username+"&password="+password+"&AUTH_TYPE=RESTAUTH",
  }).then(function successCallback(response){
      console.log(response);
      return response;
  },function errorCallback(response){
      console.log(response);
      return response;
  });
}
```

And the controller implementing it

```
app.controller('logInCtrl',function($scope,$http,$browser,$cookies,userOperation,pnotifyService,$rootScope,$timeout){
$scope.login = function(){
    userOperation.loginService($scope.username,$scope.password).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $timeout(function(){
            console.log($cookies.get('JSESSIONID'));
            console.log($cookies);

          },4000);     

    });
}
```

});

The response is null object;

But using advanced rest client i am getting the cookie value.Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Note:All angular cdns are of version 1.5.8.

Comment: let me know is that data available in under application cookies ??

Comment: @Chowdary Havnt understand you

Comment: is that cookie data setted in your browser??

Comment: @Chowdary How i can check that? I have opened the console and checked the cookie array but there was not data present there

Comment: inspect--go to Appication tab--left side there is folder named cookies---in that select your domain.Here u can see the cookie data

Comment: @Chowdary i have inspected and gone to resources tab and checked the cookies section.Is is correct?